# AWS SWF - How can I pass an argument to a a workflow task?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I am just starting out with the AWS Flow Framework for Java. Essentially I am trying to extend the [HelloWorld tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/getting-started-example-helloworldworkflow.html) but have hit a wall.

I have defined a new method `autoScale` in the interface which accepts a `String` arguement as follows

```
public interface GreeterActivities {
   public String getName();
   public String getGreeting(String name);
   public void say(String what);
   public void autoScale(String groupName);
}
```

Implementation is fairly straight forward too.

Finally in the `GreeterWorkflowImpl` class, I am calling the new `Task` as follows

```
public void greet() {
   Promise<String> name = operations.getName();
   Promise<String> greeting = operations.getGreeting(name);
   operations.say(greeting);
   operations.autoScale("WebServerScalingGroup");
}
```

But I get errors  such as **AWS Error Code: ValidationError, AWS Error Message: 1 validation error detected: Value null at 'autoScalingGroupName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null**

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error appears coming from the Auto Scaling API. It probably means that activity was successfully invoked, but an exception was thrown from its implementation. How does your activity implementation looks like? Have you tried logging the fact of activity invocation and its parameters?